# Assert that every location have a value for each date in R

Tags: r

I have a dataset that has values for Y and X variables, for certain cities, and for different dates.
But the cities don't necessarily have values for all the dates, which is a problem for me.

| date | location | X | Y |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2018-10-12 | PARIS | 10 | 20 |
| 2018-10-12 | NEW YORK | 15 | 20 |
| 2018-10-13 | PARIS | 16 | 8 |
| 2018-10-13 | LOS ANGELES | 16 | 8 |

So I want, for each date, a value per city of Y and X like this :

| date | location | X | Y |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2018-10-12 | PARIS | 10 | 20 |
| 2018-10-12 | NEW YORK | 15 | 20 |
| 2018-10-12 | LOS ANGELES | NA | NA |
| 2018-10-13 | PARIS | 16 | 8 |
| 2018-10-13 | LOS ANGELES | 16 | 8 |
| 2018-10-13 | NEW YORK | NA | NA |

I tried isolating unique dates in a new dataframe and using the 'left_join' function of dplyr package but it doesn't work...
How can i achieve this ?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `expand` from the `tidyr` package to get all possible combinations of `date` and `location`, and then `left_join` to your existing data frame:

```r
cities  |>
    expand(date, location)  |>
    left_join(cities)

# Joining, by = c("date", "location")
# # A tibble: 6 x 4
#   date       location        X     Y
#   <chr>      <chr>       <int> <int>
# 1 2018-10-12 LOS ANGELES    NA    NA
# 2 2018-10-12 NEW YORK       15    20
# 3 2018-10-12 PARIS          10    20
# 4 2018-10-13 LOS ANGELES    16     8
# 5 2018-10-13 NEW YORK       NA    NA
# 6 2018-10-13 PARIS          16     8
```